# Match once but not repetitions

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following code to match:

> String(s) in which `.` is not present consecutively, it can be alternatively

```js
let strArr = [
  '#foo3.5', // true
  '#bar34..34', // false
  '.', // true
  '#ipv4-1.1.1.1' // true
];

const re = /^([^.]*\.[^.]*)+$/;

strArr.map(
  (val, idx) => console.log(`${idx}: ${re.test(val)}`)
);
```

But, the above code also matches `#bar34..34`, which is **not** desired. I tried changing the `*` meta-character in my pattern to `+`, but then, it fails to match `.` and `#ipv4-1.1.1.1` strings.

Also, I want my regex to be **small**, because it is a part of a *very* long regex (you can suppose it an Email ID regex). So, what should be the required regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match a whole string with no consecutive dots:

```
/^(?!.*\.\.).*$/
```